# Failed to restored indexes using mongorestore - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

> Note: I already know about --noIndexRestore

I have an org collection with the following document structure,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc2bf9f5ca45131b8f8e427"),
    "name" : "National",
    "parent" : "null",
    "level" : 1,
    "label" : "National",
    "identifier" : "Default",
    "client_id" : ObjectId("5af3178c141292374cbf363e")
}
```

I have created the indexes on the following fields,

1. name
2. parent
3. level
4. identifier
5. client_id

When I check indexes,

```
db.org.getIndexes();
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "name" : 1
    },
    "name" : "name_1",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
},

/* 3 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "parent" : 1
    },
    "name" : "parent_1",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
},

/* 4 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "level" : 1
    },
    "name" : "level_1",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
},

/* 5 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "identifier" : 1
    },
    "name" : "identifier_1",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
},

/* 6 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "client_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "client_id_1",
    "ns" : "testdbname.org"
}
```

All of the above indexes looks fine to me. But when I take backup on server and restore it somewhere else it gives me the following error while restoring the org collection.

```
reading metadata for testdbname.org from archive 'testdbname_05-10-2019_00%3A55%3A31.archive'
2019-10-05T10:20:40.979+0500    restoring testdbname.org from archive 'testdbname_05-10-2019_00%3A55%3A31.archive'
2019-10-05T10:20:41.226+0500    reading metadata for testdbname.questionbank from archive 'testdbname_05-10-2019_00%3A55%3A31.archive'
2019-10-05T10:20:41.237+0500    restoring indexes for collection testdbname.org from metadata
2019-10-05T10:20:41.240+0500    Failed: testdbname.org: error creating indexes for testdbname.org: createIndex error: Values in v:2 index key pattern cannot be of type object. Only numbers > 0, numbers < 0, and strings are allowed.
```

Answer (score 4):

For the people who will come here in the future the issue was, I was using MongoDB 4.0 on the local and server was on 4.2:

Starting in version 4.2, mongodump uses Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical) format for the metadata files. To parse these files for restore, use mongorestore version 4.2+ that supports Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical or Relaxed mode) format. 
For details please see "Metadata Format" section on this : [docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)